# like clause in sub query not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables designs and stores, I need to get designs where store id is 'something' and particular on that store id that design should allow.

Example - store id is '401274' then I want designs that should belong to store id= '401274' and on that store id(401274) that design id should be available in design_id_allowed column of store, I have written a subquery but it not working here is syntax error

My query is,

```
   SELECT `designs`.`id`, (SELECT  `stores`.`id` as 'store_id'  FROM `stores` WHERE  `stores`.`id`='401274' And `stores`.`design_id_allowed` like '%#'.`designs`.`id`.'#%') FROM `designs` WHERE `designs`.`store_id` = '401274'
```

Error is,

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near 'SELECT `stores`.`id` as 'store_id' FROM `stores` WHERE
> `stores`.`id`='401274'' at line 1

In store table, designs are id's entry like this,
[image]

Comment: replace  \`stores\`.'design_id_allowed'  with  \`stores\`.\`design_id_allowed\`

Comment: Please don't edit your mistakes otherwise no sense of below answers!!

Comment: My mistake I will take care of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this buddy -**

```
SELECT
  `designs`.`id`,
  (SELECT  `stores`.`id` as 'store_id'  FROM `stores` WHERE  `stores`.`id`='401274' And `stores`.`design_id_allowed` like '%2629%')
FROM `designs`
WHERE `designs`.`store_id` = '401274'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to change your query to

```
SELECT
  `designs`.`id`,
  (SELECT  `stores`.`id` as 'store_id'  FROM `stores` WHERE  `stores`.`id`='401274' And `stores`.`design_id_allowed` like '%2629%')
FROM `designs`
WHERE `designs`.`store_id` = '401274'
```

php

```
$db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);

$sql = "
    SELECT
      `designs`.`id`,
      (SELECT  `stores`.`id` as 'store_id'  FROM `stores` WHERE  `stores`.`id`='".$db->quote($var1)."' And `stores`.`design_id_allowed` like '%".$db->quote($var2)."%')
    FROM `designs`
    WHERE `designs`.`store_id` = '401274'
";

 $data = $db->query($sql)->fetchAll();
```

Comment: It run without error now I have to pass dynamic design id like  SELECT
  `designs`.`id`,
  (SELECT  `stores`.`id` as 'store_id'  FROM `stores` WHERE  `stores`.`id`='401274' And `stores`.`design_id_allowed` like '%#'. `designs`.`id`.'#%') as 'store_id'
FROM `designs`
WHERE `designs`.`store_id` = '401274'

Answer (score 1):

Column name separated by `,`

```
SELECT `designs`.`id`, (SELECT  `stores`..
                    ^^^^^// add comma
```

Comment: It run without error now I have to pass dynamic design id like SELECT designs.id, (SELECT stores.id as 'store_id' FROM stores WHERE stores.id='401274' And stores.design_id_allowed like '%#'. designs.id.'#%') as 'store_id' FROM designs WHERE designs.store_id = '401274'

Comment: No you just pass dynamic id as `design_id_allowed like '%YOUR_ID%') `

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expression in query like

```
WHERE `designs`.`store_id` REGEXP '^#[0-9]+,#[0-9]+$'
```